# rCharts: NVD3, can I create plot right in R?

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, d3.js

I want to use NVD3 charts and rCharts for my project. However I'm still struggling with the first steps. How and where can I implement these charts? Right in R? Probably not, that's why I've tried to generate a HTML website with the generated Java Script code, but this isn't showing anything either. Where is my mistake?

My R code:

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')
require(rCharts)

hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = "multiBarChart")
n1$print("chart3")
```

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 


        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 

<html lang="en"> 


<head> 


    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <title>Title Goes Here</title> 

</head> 

<body> 

<div id = 'chart3' class = 'rChart nvd3'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      drawchart3()
    });
    function drawchart3(){  
      var opts = {
 "dom": "chart3",
"width":    800,
"height":    400,
"x": "Hair",
"y": "Freq",
"group": "Eye",
"type": "multiBarChart",
"id": "chart3" 
},
        data = [
 {
 "Hair": "Black",
"Eye": "Brown",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             32 
},
{
 "Hair": "Brown",
"Eye": "Brown",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             53 
},
{
 "Hair": "Red",
"Eye": "Brown",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             10 
},
{
 "Hair": "Blond",
"Eye": "Brown",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":              3 
},
{
 "Hair": "Black",
"Eye": "Blue",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             11 
},
{
 "Hair": "Brown",
"Eye": "Blue",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             50 
},
{
 "Hair": "Red",
"Eye": "Blue",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             10 
},
{
 "Hair": "Blond",
"Eye": "Blue",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             30 
},
{
 "Hair": "Black",
"Eye": "Hazel",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             10 
},
{
 "Hair": "Brown",
"Eye": "Hazel",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             25 
},
{
 "Hair": "Red",
"Eye": "Hazel",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":              7 
},
{
 "Hair": "Blond",
"Eye": "Hazel",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":              5 
},
{
 "Hair": "Black",
"Eye": "Green",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":              3 
},
{
 "Hair": "Brown",
"Eye": "Green",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":             15 
},
{
 "Hair": "Red",
"Eye": "Green",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":              7 
},
{
 "Hair": "Blond",
"Eye": "Green",
"Sex": "Male",
"Freq":              8 
} 
]

      if(!(opts.type==="pieChart" || opts.type==="sparklinePlus" || opts.type==="bulletChart")) {
        var data = d3.nest()
          .key(function(d){
            //return opts.group === undefined ? 'main' : d[opts.group]
            //instead of main would think a better default is opts.x
            return opts.group === undefined ? opts.y : d[opts.group];
          })
          .entries(data);
      }

      if (opts.disabled != undefined){
        data.map(function(d, i){
          d.disabled = opts.disabled[i]
        })
      }

      nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models[opts.type]()
          .width(opts.width)
          .height(opts.height)

        if (opts.type != "bulletChart"){
          chart
            .x(function(d) { return d[opts.x] })
            .y(function(d) { return d[opts.y] })
        }










       d3.select("#" + opts.id)
        .append('svg')
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

       nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
       return chart;
      });
    };
</script>

</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you would normally display javascript charts in a browser. I'd suggest making a simple shiny web page to display them, and perhaps provide interactivity to the input data set.

Comment: You don't load NVD3.js in your html/javascript.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but instead of `n1$print("chart3")`, what do you get when you just do `n1`?